# Windows Server 2008 R2 on Mac Mini (Mid-2011) - Loads of errors after install

Tags: mac, windows-server-2008-r2, mac-mini

I've been trying to install Windows Server 2008 R2 on my Mac Mini (late 2011 model, purchased this week from my local Apple store). Installation happens fine without any issues, but after setup is complete I get a load of errors.

When I login I get this error:

```
Windows Server Initial Configuration Tasks has stopped working
(Problem details says:
CLR20r3, oobe.exe, System.ArgumentOutOfRange
```

When I dismiss that and open Server Management I get this error in the MMC window:

```
MMC could not create the snap-in.
MMC could not create the snap-in. The snap-in might not have been installed correctly.
Name: Server Manager
CLSID: FX:{18ea3d92-d6aa-41d9-a205-2023400c8fbb}
```

It's the same error when I try to open the Event Viewer:

```
MMC could not create the snap-in.
MMC could not create the snap-in. The snap-in might not have been installed correctly.
Name: Even Viewer
CLSID: FX:{b05566ad-fe9c-4363-be05-7a4cbb7cb510}
```

These problems seem to be related to the .NET Framework installation. The installation media is an ISO of the latest version of WS2008R2 (with SP1) from MSDN.

This happens repeatedly and I don't know what to do.

**What can I do to correct these errors?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to sucessfully install Windows Server (using the same DVD) on another computer perfectly fine so I thought to get at the setup logs and compare the two and see what went wrong.

As I was going through the setup logs (C:\Windows\Panther...) I noticed the date/time column read "1899-01-01" - I thought nothing of it, but couldn't see anything wrong in the logs.

Then it hit me: I glanced at the lower-right corner of the screen, the computer's date was set to 1st January, 10010.

After changing the system date and time back to the correct value things started working again, however just to be on the safe-side I'm going to reinstall Windows Server on the Mac (in case the out-of-range date corrupted anything).

Not sure how this happened; The date and time were set correctly within OS X Lion.